# Que significa este codigo y que se quiere hacer con esta expresion?

Tags: java

//server se refiere a un atributo de tipo Servidor que es una clase

server.clientes

```
.stream()
.filter(h -> (destinatario.equals(h.getIdentificador())))
.forEach((h) -> h.enviarMensaje(lista));
```

Comment: Podrias editar la pregunta y formatear el codigo.

Comment: Josep Monclus quizas asi se vea mejor

Comment: Yo no se porque se pide el cierre (o los -1) y me imagino que el OP menos, pues nadie le dice nada, pero este tipo de preguntas creo que estan permitidas, en javascript he visto muchas preguntando que hace tal o cual codigo. Saludos

Comment: Coincido contigo. Este tipo de preguntas está permitida, pero hay que mejorarla. Como ya tiene una respuesta con votos positivos, la pregunta no corre el riesgo de ser borrada.

Comment: @AngelAngel Puede ser porque no se ve que haya intentado nada para saber qué hace. Una búsqueda rápida te lleva hacia varios enlaces de Java 8 y lambdas. Para lo demás hace falta más código (por ejemplo `enviarMensaje(lista)`) Sin más código hay que hacer suposiciones así que no está claro lo que pregunta, ni da un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable. Son normas. Si añadimos que está haciendo preguntas sin molestarse a ganar la medalla de informado para saber lo básico de como usar el sitio, creo que hay razones de sobra. Si en javascript se hace mal diles que lo hagan bien no al revés.

Comment: Hola @fvf. Bienvenido a [es.so]... Creo que una pregunta de este estilo, sí bien es totalmente válida, podría dar un poco más de información a quien quiera ayudarte (ayudanos a ayudarte).  Para alguien que no está en tu lugar, la pregunta da muy poco contexto. No explica qué se está haciendo ni de dónde salió ese fragmento, ni por qué estás interesado en entenderlo, ni nada que nos de alguna pista del objetivo... Te recomiendo [edit] la pregunta agregando algo de esto, y sería bueno que realices el [tour] y leer [ask]... La idea es ofrecer un [mcve] en todas las preguntas

Comment: @Awes0meM4n yo no digo que en javascript sino lo pongo como ejemplo de que este tipo de preguntas han tenido buena acceptacion, (mi punto de vista lo expuse en el chat si quieres pasarte y leerlo, yo para no repetirme). *...Una búsqueda rápida te lleva hacia varios enlaces de Java 8 y lambdas...* bueno si pero tambien depende del OP y de muchos en el chat comento algo sobre esto. Saludos

Answer (score 2):

Tu codigo utiliza Streams es una nueva funcionalidad integrada desde Java 8
y quiere decir lo Siguiente:

```
.stream()  //convierte una Lista (java.util.List) a una instancia stream
.filter(h -> (destinatario.equals(h.getIdentificador()))) //solo deja en el stream a los elementos que retornen true en el siguiente fragmento (destinatario.equals(h.getIdentificador())
.forEach((h) -> h.enviarMensaje(lista)); //el metodo forEach() recibe un Consumer el cual debe ser una instruccion con resultado void y la ejecuta con todos los elementos restantes del stream
```

Espero te sirva , Saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias :)

Comment: @fvf Bienvenido a stackoverflow en español, puede que le interese leer esto http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour, asi entender un poco como funciona el sitio y tambien podria echar un vistazo a esto otro link http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask .Saludos

Comment: @fvf P.D: quizas le interese mirar algo sobre **lambda Expressions** si no las conoce. Saludos